# tomcat6 & apache2 virtual hosting

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat6

I've apache2 and tomcat6 running on port 80 on ubuntu server 9.10. I've a registered domain name and I'll access the jsp index page navigating to http://abc.mydomain.com. The page is under tomcat_home/webapps/myapp and the below are tomcat virtual hosting in server.xml file:

```
<Host name="abc.mydomain.com" debug="0" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true">
<Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger"
directory="logs" prefix="virtual_log1." suffix=".log" timestamp="true"/>
<Context path="" docBase="/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapps" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

Recently a new domain has been bought(xyz.mydomain.com) and I'm asked to do the virtual hosting so that the new domain name directly points the page "admin.jsp" which is located under 'tomcat_home/webapps/myapps/WE-INF/js/'(can be accessed pointing to http://abc.mydomain.com/admin). How could I do this?

If I type http://abc.mydomain.com/admin  I'll get the page what I wanted. I should access this page just by typing http://xyz.mydomain.com. Is there any url redirection or I could define any alias in tomcat virtualhosting?. Need help...

Answer (score 1):

Try [nesting the admin web app](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/host.html#Nested_Components) via a `<Context>` element in the server.xml within an additional

```
 <Host name="xyz.mydomain.com" ...>
```

In addition to your current

```
<Host name="abc.mydomain.com" debug="0" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true">
<Logger className="org.apache.catalina.logger.FileLogger"
directory="logs" prefix="virtual_log1." suffix=".log" timestamp="true"/>
<Context path="" docBase="/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapps" debug="0" reloadable="true"/>
</Host>
```

add this

```
<Host name="xyz.mydomain.com" appBase="webapps"> 
    <Context path="" docBase="/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapps"/> 
      </Host>
```

If `path` is set to `""` then you can get the app at the `ROOT` context, like `xyz.mycompany.com` instead of `xyz.mycompany.com/myapps`

Now move your **admin.jsp to the root of the web app**, so move it out of `'tomcat_home/webapps/myapps/WE-INF/js/` into

```
/usr/share/tomcat/webapps/myapps
```

and finally in the `web.xml` of your myapps web app, add an entry to make admin.jsp the home page like so

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>admin.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: one doubt!. if the welcome page is admin.jsp won't it affect the other domain name(abc.mydomain.com)?

Comment: yes it could. since the web app is the same, so you might have to try and duplicate your web app. not a good idea - I admit